# php cUrl multiple request - get all content

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I'm using the following script to get the contents from multiple urls, but without any modifications it will run forever: https://raw.github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl/master/EpiCurl.php

I'm trying to get the contents of multiple urls, parallel. It's intended to always get an result.

Question: why is this script running forever and not terminating after some time as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You should add code below. It adds a timeout to the connection after a fixed time.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
```

Comment: Try this for your script and let me know if it works for you..!

Comment: When I add a timeout, some URLs will timeout. This will give the undesired result: no response. How can I fix this?